# FastCGI: Access denied

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, fastcgi

I'm trying to set up FastCGI caching for my wordpress website running on nginx and using PHP-FPM. Currently, when I try to visit the site, all I get is a bland "`Access denied.`".

If I comment out `fastcgi_cache drm_custom_cache` from my nginx server block, everything works just fine.

`tail /var/log/nginx/error.log` first said:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/domain.tld/html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: /ip masked/, server: domain.tld, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.tld"

In response to the error, I tried adding `security.limit_extensions =` to `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`.

Now, the error log states:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Success in Unknown on line 0
>   Unable to open primary script: /var/www/domain.tld/html (Permission denied)" while reading response header from upstream, client: /ip masked/, server: domain.tld, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.tld"

Help appreciated.

Comment: What is your file system permission in /var/www/domain.tld/html?

Comment: @Gnought 755 on directories which I set and the remaining come from the wordpresss zip (the permissions are already set correctly. All the directories and files belong to nginx:nginx. The permissions are correct (as I said, the website is fine without `fastcgi_cache drm_custom_cache` in the server block.

Comment: What is the fastcgi cache path?

Comment: @Gnought `/dev/shm/nginx/`. I also tried `/var/cache/nginx/` I think.

Comment: And what is the permission of the fastcgi cache path?

Comment: @Gnought Well I'm not sure what's supposed to be, but I just tried 777, I don't think it changed anyhing.